# add new validator column to existing collection in java for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

i am trying to add new validated column for existing empty collection in java integrated to mongodb.

```
Bson validators = Filters.and(Filters.type(column, BsonType.DECIMAL128));

UpdateOptions upsert = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

MongoDatabase db=mongodbConnection.getDatabase(db); 

MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(collname);

Document cursor=new Document(); 

Bson Document = new Document("$set",validators);

collection.updateOne(cursor, Document,upsert);
```

but produces below error

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$AndFilter

kindly help on this

Comment: i even tried same in shell script,but no luck

Comment: db.address.update({},{$set:{validator:{score:{$type:"int"}}}})
getting error  "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$type' in 'validator.score.$type' is not valid for storage."